# How to configure Spring Data JPA to only read the schema?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I am writing a web service using Spring Boot to fetch some data from the database and perform some operations on it.

The database is standalone which is linked to other web service, so I do not want  my web service to interfere with the schema and other data.
I just want my service to connect to the database and only perform read operations.

So what should be configurations, I do so that it does not interfere with the current database in any manner.

```
// Example Configuration :
# Connection url for the database "test"
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test?useSSL=false
# Username and password
spring.datasource.username = root
spring.datasource.password = root
# Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, update): with "update" the database
# schema will be automatically updated accordingly to java entities found in the project
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate
```

So how should I change my configuration to achieve read only mode?

Comment: you can create your own repositories by extending Repositry interface from spring data jpa and use it as readonly operations only.

Comment: Yes, I have read a few answers about repository, what about no schema change configuration?

Comment: Don't use the `root` user. Create a user that has read-only rights on the schema and use that user for the web service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate` as the default behaviour is `none`.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html

> spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto= # DDL mode. This is actually a shortcut for the "hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" property. Defaults to "create-drop" when using an embedded database and no schema manager was detected. Otherwise, defaults to "none".

Incidentally, this wouldn't have modified the database, but would have just failed if your domain entities don't match with what Hibernate is expecting.